# Port 5432 still closed despite firewall exemption in Windows. Cannot connect Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, networking, windows-firewall

I have been working on this problem for 2 days. I have a postgres db running on my Windows 10 machine which I can connect to with no problem as localhost.  However, when I try to connect via the public Ipv4 address (either through a different machine on the same network or even the same Windows machine), I get the typical *"Connection timed out, is the server running on host %public ipv4% and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"*.

I have edited the pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files so my public ipv4 address is allowed.  It is not a problem with settings in these files. The port also does seem to be listening for connections, using netstat -na:
`TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING`

What seems to be the problem is that when I check if port 5432 is open using portchecker.co or https://canyouseeme.org/ , I get closed or timed out.  This is despite making an exception in my Windows firewall settings for 5432, and then when that didn't work, **even disabling the Windows firewall entirely**.  Maybe there is another firewall somewhere on my local machine that is blocking inbound connections to 5432, but I have no idea where to look. Can anyone point me in a direction where I can open this port up?

Comment: The `netstat` is showing `IPV6` addresses and the error seems to be about not finding a `IPV4` address.  What is `listen_addresses` set to in `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Listen addresses is set to ‘*’

Comment: Since the default is `localhost` did you restart the server after changing to `*`? Have you tried to connect using the public  IPV6 address?

Comment: There can be any number of firewalls between two machines, they don't have to be just on the machines themselves.  You might have a home router with a built-in firewall which is blocking things.

Comment: How would I check my home wifi router's firewalls?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Ok, thank you, I can connect via Ipv6!  I wonder why Ipv4 is not working? Here is how my pg_hba.conf looks (stars for privacy):
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             172.***.***.8/32        scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host    all             all             2603:8000:****:****:8971:****:****:5f9/128       scram-sha-256
host    all             all             2603:8000:****:****:1dc7:****:****:8f5/128

Comment: Add the `pg_hba.conf` contents to question properly formatted. Though this is not the issue as `pg_hba.conf` has nothing to do with what address and port the server is listening on. It controls user access from the either `local` or `host` connections. Again, **did you restart the server** after changing `listen_addresses` to `*`? Also has the line been un-commented?  Because as your `netstat` output shows the server is not listening on a IPV4 address.

Comment: @jjanes, the `netstat` output, if it is correct, does not show the server listening on IPv4 address.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver but without a firewall problem on top of that, the error message should be a simple 'connection refused', not a time out.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Hi Adrian, I did restart the server several times.  Interestingly though, the default setting (Postgres 15) for listen_addresses was * - I did not have to ever change it from localhost.  The line was also default uncommented.

Comment: Is this running in WSL by any chance? Are you sure the `netstat` command is not showing a `IPV4` address for the server?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Hi Adrian.  No just Windows 10.  I double checked netstat, you're right it is listening IPV4 looks like `TCP  0.0.0.0:5432    0.0.0.0:0   LISTENING` ..  `TCP   [::]:5432     [::]:0   LISTENING`. I'm stuck.  The difference in using the IPV6 vs IPV4 is that I can connect using the IPV6 (instead of localhost) only on the computer running the db (`Connection Refused` using IPV4).  On another machine on the same network I cannot connect using either IPv, although there is a difference, in that I get `Connection Refused` error using IPV4 and `Operation Timed Out` using the IPV6.

Comment: Well the second case(remote machine) I would say is due to a firewall blocking the port. The first case I really can't answer. My suspicion is it is due internal networking, I just don't know Windows well enough to be any more specific.